# ASP.NET using gmail with smtp error: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond.."

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, model-view-controller, smtp

I'm trying to add a new email confirmation method to my MVC site, so whenever a user registers he will receive a confirmation email. The problem is, that no matter what code I use (I've found some different options on GitHub) I always get the same error:

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 66.102.1.108:587".

The code I used is:

```
using ATMProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ATMProject.Services
{
    public class SendEmailConfirmation
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string fullname { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string random { get; set; }

        public SendEmailConfirmation(string Email, string Fullname, 
          string Username, string Random) 
        {
            email = Email;
            fullname = Fullname;
            username = Username;
            random = Random;
        }

        public void sendEmail ()
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new 
              System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "123456");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            #region Msg
            msg.Subject = "Hello " + fullname;
            msg.Body = "Hello " + fullname + 
              "Thanks for Registering in Budgetize...Your Account Details are given below:";
            msg.Body += "<tr>";
            msg.Body += "<td>User Name :" + username + "</td>";
            msg.Body += "</tr>";
            msg.Body += "<tr>";
            msg.Body += "<td>Activation Number :" + random + "</td>";
            msg.Body += "</tr>";
            msg.Body += "<tr>";
            msg.Body += "<td>Thanking</td><td>Team Budgetize</td>";
            msg.Body += "</tr>";
            #endregion

            string toAddress = email; // Add Recepient address
            msg.To.Add(toAddress);
            string fromAddress = "\"Budgetize \" <example@example.com>";
            msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            try {smtp.Send(msg);}
            catch (Exception ex) {throw;}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that you haven't put your real passoword there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: What do you mean by secure connection? I used ssl (smtp.enablessl = true)

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GMAIL-Error-The-SMTP-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated.aspx

I think your email are not authenticated.

Comment: Hey, I found the solution! you can see it in the comment below :)

Answer (score 3):

**I found the solution!** I've run the same code on a different computer (home computer) and it worked well. It seems like **the port (587) was blocked in my work pc** by another layer of security (firewall did not block it, neither did the antivirus). The IT Manager said he's blocking many ports with another layer, which I don't have access to. If the same bug occurs in your work pc - try running it on a different pc (that is not connected to the same network) and look if the code works.